# Video compression estimated size - android

Tags: android, video, video-compression

I am developing an android video compression application.

I have video 1280*720, video duration is 4 seconds and size of the video is 7Mb, How can get estimated video size for different resolutions.

I want to find estimated video size for 854*504, 640*360 and more resolutions, please let me if any formal for calculating estimated video size.

Thanks :)

Comment: do you want something like [this](http://toolstud.io/video/filesize.php?imagewidth=1920&imageheight=1080&framerate=25&timeduration=60&timeunit=seconds)?

Comment: Yes exactly, how can i achive it programmatically.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the js in that page I linked :D

Answer (score 0):

You can not estimate file size from resolution alone. A file with little motion will compress much smaller that a file with a lot of action. If you need to know the size before compression, you should decide what size you want, then divide that number by the video duration, and use that number for your bitrate when encoding.

Comment: I have resolution, bitrate and time can i calculate file size